# Initialize Realm object with @PrimaryKey 0 (zero) fails on second object

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour when trying to initialize a simple Realm object. I have a JSONArray which looks like that:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Biatrix"},{"id":1,"name":"Bill"},{"id":2,"name":"O-ren"}]
```

I have the following simple Realm class:

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import io.realm.annotations.Required;

public class Assassin extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @Required
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to populate the class (in Kotlin):

```
val assassins = viperData.getJSONArray("assassins")

for (i in 0..(assassins.length() - 1)) {
    val item = assassins.getJSONObject(i)

    var assassin = realm.createObject(Assassin::class.java)
    assassin.setId(item.getInt("id"))
    assassin.setName(item.getString("name"))
}
```

The first item which has id=0 is created fine, but the in the second item I get an exception `io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 0`. Then I thought oh ya, the object is created pr. default with a id=0 and only afterwords I change the value to something else. It's failing because it allready has an item with the value 0. So I set the id=-1 in the class:

```
...
public class Assassin extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id = -1;
...
```

... but still get the same exception.

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

**Update**

I removed the `@PrimaryKey` annotation and the class populated correctly. Just to show that the values are unique, here is a shot of the realm class containing the values (the actual values - no assassins here...):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From realm documentation:

When calling Realm.createObject(), it will return a new object with all fields set to the default value. In this case, there might be a conflict with an existing object whose primary key field is the default value. To avoid this, it is suggested to create a standalone object, set values of the fields, and then copy it to Realm by copyToRealm() method.

Comment: I understand what you say, but this is not the issue. The issue here is why does the initialization fail when the `id` values I deliver are obviously unique?

Comment: OR there could be a bug as I suggested in my post, because I checked the values quite a few times to be sure, and they are undoubtedly unique. See my update.

Comment: Well I'm using realm just at the moment and setting ids with method I provided works perfectly fine, so there's no bug here. I don't know how Kotlin works and if it could be issue.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown? on createObject or on setId ?

Comment: The exception is thrown on `createObject` on the second item. So it looks like it creates a new object with default id=0 but there already exists an object with that id (first item), so it fails. This is the only reason I can think of.

Comment: Yeah you are right. From realm documentation: When calling Realm.createObject(), it will return a new object with all fields set to the default value. In this case, there might be a conflict with an existing object whose primary key field is the default value. To avoid this, it is suggested to create a standalone object, set values of the fields, and then copy it to Realm by copyToRealm() method.

Comment: Thanks Wukash. Please update your post so I can accept it as the answer.